# Debug not working in PhpStorm with server on VM

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I set myself up a Debian server on VirtualBox, everything works great except Xdebug which won't start. On server I have Symfony 3 app which use `vhost admin.localwww.pl` with HTTPS.

My `php -v` result:

```
PHP 7.3.31-2+0~20211022.89+debian11~1.gbp745ac7 (cli) (built: Oct 22 2021 12:37:38) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.31, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.31-2+0~20211022.89+debian11~1.gbp745ac7, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

My xdebug.ini

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9003
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

My PhpStorm settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I run PHP Remote Debug configuration I see this:

[image]

Regardless if I add `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM` to the URL or if I use Xdebug Helper in Google Chrome, the effect is the same: nothing happens despite the breakpoint was set.

I use PHP CLI from remote server which is on VM:

[image]

---

EDIT: My current config but still doesn't work:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port = 9003
```

Comment: Does PHPStorm run on a VM? Or PHP runs on VM and PHPstorm on the host?

Comment: @viko PHP Storm on host, PHP+nginx+php-fpm on VM

Comment: PHP xdebug has to connect with the host. So `client_host` parameter should go to host. Please try to ping the host from VM and use this IP/hostname in this parameter. I can guess it should be: `xdebug.client_host = 10.0.2.2`

Comment: @viko You're right, now I got "There was a problem sending 179 bytes on socket 6: Broken pipe"

Comment: Hmm, try: `xdebug.discover_client_host = 1` or 9003 port is busy

Comment: Still this same error. I change port to 9010 but still same error

Comment: Maybe the host is invalid. Run it on the VM: `telnet 10.0.2.2 9003` or did you restart fpm?

Comment: `xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1` -- this is WRONG. It's Xdebug that connects to PhpStorm and NOT other way around. That should be the IP of your host OS where PhpStorm is running (as seen from inside the VM). Try `xdebug.discover_client_host = 1` and see what Xdebug log will say for that (what IP is used). Also check `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` -- what IP it has? Also check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw

Comment: @viko When I restart server all works :D

Comment: @PawelC - Cool :) You are welcome -> miłej zabawy.

Answer (score 4):

All your settings refer to Xdebug 2 settings, where you are using Xdebug 3.1.1 — please read the upgrade guide: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Comment: This config it's ok 
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port = 9003

Comment: I have done so that I keep the page files on macOS, the server is on Virtualbox and the directory with the page is connected to it using Shared Folders

Answer (score 1):

Please use function xdebug_info() on any page for receiveing diagnostic data.
Also please setup xdebug_log.

Comment: [903] [Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 127.0.0.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
[903] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9003.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Haha, perfect answer. Solved the problem in 2 secs.